# ε-regular pair (A, B) includes $K_{3,3}$ subgraph

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory, bipartite-graphs, extremal-combinatorics, extremal-graph-theory

> Let G consist of just a single ε-regular pair (A, B) of density d > 0, with |A| = |B| = l. Prove that
> for any d, we have that if ε is sufficiently small and ` is sufficiently large, then we can find a $K_{3,3}$ subgraph of $A \cup B$.

I am trying to use the lemma below to prove the above statement:

*"For ε-regular pair (A, B) of density d > 0, and $Y \subset B$ have size $|Y| \ge \epsilon|B|$, all but fewer than $\epsilon|A|$ of the vertices in A have $\ge (d-\epsilon)*|Y|$ neighbors in Y."*

So I let $Y \subset B$ with size $|Y| \ge \epsilon|B|$. Then I assume $ε=d/2$ and $l \ge 6/d$, which means that almost all vertices in A have greater or equal than $(d-\epsilon)*|Y|=d/2*6/d=3$ neighbors in Y, which is a subset of B.

However, in order to form a $K_{3,3}$, I need to show that more than 3 vertices in Y have at least 3 neighbors in A as well, which I am stuck on. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Here is the vague idea: find a vertex in A with |N(a)| about d|B| (your lemma says there are plenty such vertices, and I am ignoring writing -\epsilon).  Now find another vertex in A with at least d|N(a)| = d^2 |B| neighbors in N(a) (again lemma says there are plenty). Finally find a third vertex in A adjacent to a d-fraction of the common neighbors from before. This all works as long as \epsilon is small enough...I don't think \epsilon=d/2 is going to cut it

Comment: @dbal i am not sure what d-fraction is, is it $d^2|N(a)|$ which is again by the lemma?? thx

Comment: yeah! d fraction of the set of size d|N(a)| would be d^2|N(a)|.

Comment: thanks! and can you give me an intuitive explanation behind the lemma? i seem to understand your proof now (i filled in the holes with l and epsilon values) but i dont have an intuitive understanding of the lemma

Comment: The intuition behind an epsilon regular pair is that it "looks like" a random bipartite graph with edge density d. In a random graph with density d, when you look at a vertex in A, you expect it to have d|B| neighbors in B, and more generally, you expect it to have d|Y| neighbors in Y for any Y subset of B. So the lemma just says that given Y, most vertices in A have the "correct" amount of neighbors in Y